# What caused launch abort on SpaceX's Bangabandhu-1 launch

Tags: spacex, launch, falcon-9, launch-sequence

On Thursday, May 10th, 2018, SpaceX attempted a launch of the first Falcon 9 block V rocket carrying Bangabandhu-1 however the countdown was stopped at t-58 seconds and the launch was scrubbed for 24 hours. Do we know what caused the launch abort sequence to be initiated?

Comment: So far only this tweet: "Standing down today due to a standard ground system auto abort at T-1 min. Rocket and payload are in good health—teams are working towards tomorrow’s backup launch opportunity at 4:14 p.m. EDT, or 20:14 UTC." - which is ofc not enough for an answer.

Comment: I doubt that any committee, customer or boss would accept to his *"Why did it fail again?"* question an *"it is opinion-based"* answer from the engineers. **Please vote for leave open.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Flight Computer checked everything, and noticed an abort signal in a piece of ground equipment, due to a bad state from a prior test. They have fixed the problem to not happen again.

This is from the livestream of the second launch attempt.

Comment: Just heard this in the Livestream too!